Dividing in SQL Server (calculate Weekend Transactions as a % of Total transactions)
I need to calculate "% Weekend Transactions" dividing Weekend Transactions by total number of transactions.
The column transaction_date of the Transaction_data table  has of course a date data type and it is a foreign key. In order to find the number of transactions on weekends I have joined the transaction_data table with the Calendar table.
Here is the query which returns 0 unfortunately
select (count(transaction_date) / (select count(transaction_date) from Transaction_Data)) * 100 from Transaction_Data t
left join Calendar c on c.Date = t.transaction_date
where c.Weekend = 'Y'

I know that in SQL server there some issues when dividing. In terms of numeric values the total number of transactions at weekends is 76608 and the total number of transactions is 269720,
so select (76608 / 269720.0) * 100
returns the correct output which is 28.40. As you notice I needed to add .0 otherwise the query would have returned 0 again.
My question is how can I divide 2 aggregation in SQL server?
Thanks upfront

Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results

Multiply every column by 1.0 first

Two suggestions:

Convert the numerator to a decimal value before the divide. This can be done by multiplying by 100.0 up-front as DaleK suggested above. Otherwise, you will be performing an integer divide with a likely truncated result of zero.
Eliminate the subselect and use conditional aggregation to calculate both the weekend transaction count and total transaction count. Conditional aggregation combines an aggregation function like SUM() or COUNT() with a CASE expression of IIF() function to selectively include or exclude values from each row from the aggregated result. If the condition is true, the THEN value is included. If false, the (implied) ELSE NULL value is ignored.

The result would be something like:
select
    100.00 * count(case when c.Weekend = 'Y' then 1 end)
        / count(*)
        AS WeekendTransactionPercent
from Transaction_Data t
left join Calendar c
    on c.Date = t.transaction_date

I would suggest leaving any rounding to your presentation layer, but if you prefer, you can wrap the entire expression up in a CAST(... AS DECIMAL(8, 5)), or whatever you need.
If by chance transaction_date is actually a date/time value, you will need to truncate it to just the date part for the join condition - on c.Date = CAST(t.transaction_date AS DATE).
See this db<>fiddle for a demo.
